# For the podcast live pre-show, can we pipe in the video of the globe?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, podcast

For the podcast live pre-show, can we pipe in the video of the globe showing the global hits while the office staff is getting ready for the show?

Is that feasible?

I think everyone that has seen it is enamored with it already and wants at least a 30 second glimpse of it to be amazed.

Comment: Podcast pre-show? Video of the globe? Links please :)

Comment: sadly no links, only the video in the background while they were recording the podcast. Asked Nick mid-pre-chat and he skirted around it, with a rough maybe. see here for _some_ discussion http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/512/se-podcast-live-chat